# $L$ $U$ Decomposition Not Working (not Sure what I'm doing wrong: Matlab)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, matlab

[image]

I'm given this question 14a.  The question gives me the pseudocode and I'm supposed to code it up on the algorithm or procedure in Matlab. I use this matrix for my A in my Matlab code:
[image]

I run my Matlab code but yet I keep getting incorrect results.  My L*U ends up not being equal to A.  I'm really confused as I follow the pseudocode pretty much exactly.

Here's my Matlab code:

A=[1 4 0 0; 3 4 1 0; 0 2 3 4; 0 0 1 3];

$n=4$;

$L=zeros(n,n)$;

$U=zeros(n,n)$;

$L(1,1)=A(1,1)$;

for $i=2:4$

$L(i,i-1)=A(i,i-1)$;

$U(i-1,i)=A(i-1,i)/L(i-1,i-1)$;

$L(i,i)=A(i,i)-(L(i,i-1)*U(i-1,i))$;
end

$Z=L*U$;

If someone could help me debug my code, I would really appreciate it as my L*U (which I store as Z) ends up not being equal to A and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace`U=zeros(n,n);`    by 
    `U=eye(n);`

$U$ is an upper bidiagonal matrix, we know that the diagonal entries are $1$.

Comment: Thank you.  Should I leave L as L=zeros(n,n)? Or should I change that too? Thanks again.

Comment: leave it, it seems to be doing fine.

Comment: Thank you very much.  It seems to work perfectly now!